# Angular using random browser's IP to call API

Tags: angular, networking, network-programming

I have an Angular user interface, which needs to call some API urls. I noticed that to make the API call it does not uses my IP which I get from - [whats my IP](https://whatismyipaddress.com/), instead it uses some other random IP as shown in the image.[image]

How can I make the API calls such that it uses my system IP to generate the requests instead of these random browser's IP?